# How to change a Tailwind Class based on React State/Props

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, class-names

I'm trying to do a Progress Bar Component.

I'm using these versions:

```json
"next": "13.4.4",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"classnames": "^2.3.2",
```

I want to change the width (Tailwind Class) of Progress Thumb based on `currentValue` Props, but It does not work. I had this issue before, but I'm trying to find any help just now. And, I'm using `classNames()` to create better class conditionals

And that's my code:

```js
import classNames from 'classnames'
import React from 'react'

type ProgressBarProps = {
  maxValue?: number
  currentValue: number
  showNumbers?: boolean
  orientation?: 'vertical' | 'horizontal'
}

export const ProgressBar = ({
  currentValue,
  maxValue = 100,
  showNumbers = true,
  orientation = 'vertical',
}: ProgressBarProps) => { 

  return (
    <div
      className={classNames('flex items-center w-full gap-2', {
        'flex-row': orientation === 'horizontal',
        'flex-col': orientation === 'vertical',
      })}
    >

      // -> Progress Wrapper
      <div className="flex items-center w-full h-2 gap-2 rounded-md bg-third-250">

       // -> Progress Thumb
        <div
          className={classNames(`h-full bg-primary-500 `, {
            'rounded-md': maxValue === currentValue,
            'rounded-tl-md rounded-bl-md': maxValue !== currentValue,
            [`w-[${currentValue}%]`]: currentValue,
          })}
        />

      </div>

      // Irrelevant right now
      {renderNumericProgress()}

    </div>
  )
}
```

That's the result on HTML on the Chrome Console, and as you can see we have the `w-[10%]` that I'm passing as props to this component

```html
<div class="flex items-center w-full h-2 gap-2 rounded-md bg-third-250">
 <div class="h-full bg-primary-500  rounded-tl-md rounded- 
  bl-md w-[10%]">
 </div>
</div>
```

I tried, but no success:

- `` className={`w-[${currentValue}%]`} ``
- `` className={classNames(`w-[${currentValue}%]`)} ``
- `` className={twMerge(`w-[${currentValue}%]`)} ``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider the `style` attribute instead like:

```
<div
  className={classNames(`h-full bg-primary-500 `, {
    'rounded-md': maxValue === currentValue,
    'rounded-tl-md rounded-bl-md': maxValue !== currentValue,
  })}
  style={{ width: `${currentValue}%` }}
/>
```